# Does GoogleAppEngine(Python SDK) disturb GoogleAppEngine(PHP SDK)?

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine

The new launched GoodleAppEngine(PHP Version) does not work on my computer.

Every time I type in "localhost:8080", the running server returns me a "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500".
And it give me a fatal ERROR:

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'google/appengine/runtime/ApiProxy.php'
>   (include_path='/Users/xxxxx/Job_work/helloworld:/usr/local/bin/php/sdk')
>   in
>   /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/setup.php

Does that mean my Python GAE disturbs my PHP version SDK?

Comment: I have find the correct answer. The googleAppEngine file must be put in /opt/local/bin

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer. Also it's not clear to me what you mean by *googeAppEngine file* in your comment.

Comment: The same error happened again, I am confused..<br>My first attempt was to put the "google_appengine" folder in the /opt/local/bin. And it works well in the afternoon. <br> However, it fails again, the same error appears...

Comment: For me it looks like that you do not use the development server. What you describe is a file-inclusion issue in PHP (basically), I suggest you enable xdebug and then stacktraces on error and then you can take a more detailed look what is causing what.

Comment: Thanks very much, hakre. I know what happened. The problem is I also have a python version Google-App-Engine.Thus, I need to specify the "development server" to GAE-PHP-SDK and it works well now!! Thanks again, I think I will deliver such a kindness to others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much, hakre. I know what happened. The problem is I also have a python version Google-App-Engine.Thus, I need to specify the "development server" to GAE-PHP-SDK and it works well now!! Thanks again, I think I will deliver such a kindness to others in the future. – moshaholo May 26 at 12:16

Can any one tell me how to change or specify the development server to GAE-PHP-SDK.  I just started using it and don't know too much about this stuff.

P.S Sorry for posting as answer. Wasn't able to see a reply option on top.

Comment: I found the answer in another post. Linking it here hope it helps

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076200/php-gae-not-able-to-run-sdk-locally/17101832#17101832